# How to fix GGplot issue or loop issue in R while superimposing F distribution on histogram of simulations?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

What am I doing wrong in my following code?

My simulation study module asks me to use simple linear regression i.e., p=2. I'm supposed to generate B=10,000 independent simulations from a simple linear regression with N= 30 (number of observations)  and B_0=B_1=0. For each simulation, one creates a dataset and extracts the F-statistic for the global F test. Then one should verify that the histogram resembles that of an F(1, N-2) distribution. I am confused whether my loop is the problem or my ggplot code or if it's a mix of the two.

My current output looks like:

[image: Plot Output]

```
n=30
F1 = array(NA,dim=Nsim)
for(i in 1:Nsim){
  X=rnorm(n,0,sd=sigmax) # generate x
  res=rnorm(n,0,sd=sigma) # generate sigma
  Y=b0+b1*X+res # generate Y
  mod = lm(Y~X)
  res = summary(mod)
  F1[i]=res$fstatistic[1] # F statistic
}
df<-tibble(F1=F1)
x=seq(1,10,1)
y=df(x,df1 = 1, df2 = n-2)
df2 = tibble(x=x,y=y)
ggplot() +  geom_histogram(data=df, aes(x=F1,y=..density..), binwidth=0.1,color="black", fill="white")+ 
 xlab("F") +
  xlim(c(NA,10))+
  ggtitle("n=30") +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red")
```

Comment: You haven't defined `X`, so the code snippet doesn't run. Also, you seem to be extracting `res$fstatistic`, but an `lm` summary doesn't have a member called "fstatistic". Could you explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, the module I'm doing asks me to "Generate B=10,000 independent simulations from a simple liner regression with _0 = _0 = 0, and for each simulation extract the F statistic for the global F test. Verify that the histogram resembles that of an F(1,N-2) distribution. Do this exercise for N=5. " Do I define X in the loop?  I am trying to store the f-statistic for each dataset I generate and store them inside a vector.